# Symfony Rest + Oauth, token in url not in param

Tags: android, symfony, oauth

I'm working on an API with Symfony and https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle for an android app.

I'm using https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle for add security access to this API.

For now, if i want to call my api with a token, i need to do that :

```
/api/get/user/by/username/USERNAME?access_token=MYTOKEN
```

I don't want the GET parameter, i want :

```
/api/MYTOKEN/get/user/by/username/USERNAME
```

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I quote one of the owner of FOSOAuthServerBundle (https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/issues/250)

> OAuth tells that the token should be in the query string or in the
>   header. Putting it in the path does not make sense from a REST point
>   of view btw.

Comment: I asked this question on the git issue

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Authorization HTTP Header to your request

`Authorization Bearer <access_token>`

With angular, something like

```
$http({
    method: 'GET', 
    url: '/api/my/route', 
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer <access_token>'}
}).then(function(response){/* do stuff */});
```

If you don't want to use neither the header nor the GET parameter, you can define your routes to match `/api/{access_token}/my/route`. With this solution you will not be able to use the default FOSOAuthServerBundle behaviour (try to log via access_token in GET or Header). You will have to make an authentication system by your own.

Comment: haha, my mistake. I saw angular somewhere but it was not for you. I don't remove the example but it is useless here.